# PhaseScriptExecution error when trying to run npm run ios while using GoogleSignin Library

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development

So I am trying to make a signin page using react native and I am using an Pixel 7 simulator and a iphone 15 simulator as my test spaces. Now when I made a generic login screen, both simulators were able to display it, but when I tried to add a bit of code to display the google signin button, my android simulator is able to show it while my ios simulator cannot, normally it has 2 fields for username and password and when I add the google signin code it goes completely blank, and the npm run ios command returns this error

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A96B3045-2CF3-4D15-81AC-F4A1A3683462, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A96B3045-2CF3-4D15-81AC-F4A1A3683462, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/masonhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitr-felouysexwdozffdabeabaldsiti/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Fitr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fitr.build/Script-00EEFC60759A1932668264C0.sh (in target 'Fitr' from project 'Fitr')
(1 failure)
]
```

and this error in my xcode build log
[image]

This is the login screen code (note app.js is a simple file that just calls LoginScreen)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GoogleSignin,GoogleSigninButton } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: '<MY WEB CLIENT ID >',
    offlineAccess: true,
});

const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = () => {
        // Handle login logic here
        console.log(username, password);
    };


    const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
        try {
            await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
            const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
            // Here you can either send the userInfo.idToken to your backend for verification,
            // or use the userInfo to maintain session state in your application.
            console.log(userInfo);
            Alert.alert("Login Success", `User ${userInfo.user.name} logged in!`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            Alert.alert("Login Failed", error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Username"
                value={username}
                onChangeText={setUsername}
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <Button title="Login" onPress={handleLogin} />
            <Button title="Sign In with Google" onPress={handleGoogleSignIn} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 20,
        padding: 10,
    },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

This is my pod file

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '16.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Fitr' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  target 'FitrTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end
````

I've tried rerunning pod install, I made sure in the pod file the platform was on ios 16.0, when I remove the google signin piece of code the signin screen works.